# ¿Como puedo añadir elementos a un documento txt con memoria dinamica en C?

Tags: c

Estoy intentando convertir el siguiente código a memoria dinámica

Primero defino las variables.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h> //librerias necesarias para imprimir caracteres especiales
#define max_clientes 20
#define max_viajes 50

int n,i;
char nom_archivo[15];
FILE *archivo;
/************************************** STRUCTS **********************************************/
struct cliente{
    char dni[9]; //Habrá un if para comprobar que el DNI introducido es único
    char nombre[20];
    char apellidos[80];
    char direccion[150];
}clientes[max_clientes]; //Asumimos que habra un maximo de 10 clientes
```

Tras esto creo la función addcliente()

```
    void addcliente()
{

    if(clientes[n].dni[0]=='\0'){
        printf("\nIntroduce el nombre del archivo: \nNombre por defecto: clientes.txt\n\n");
        gets(nom_archivo);
        fflush(stdin);
        //Cuando abrimos el fichero le tenemos que poner rw para que podamos escribir y leer.
        archivo=fopen(nom_archivo,"rw");
        if ((archivo = fopen(nom_archivo, "rw")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "\n\nEl archivo no existe.");
            system("cls"); //En windows limpia pantalla
        }else
        {
            int i;
            printf("\n\nArchivo cargado correctamente.|\n");
            for(i=0; i<max_clientes;i++){
                fscanf(archivo,"\n %s %s %s %s",clientes[i].dni,clientes[i].nombre,clientes[i].apellidos,clientes[i].direccion);
            }
            for(i=0;i<max_clientes;i++)
            {
                if(clientes[i].dni[0]=='\0')
                {
                    //Crear un nuevo cliente y almacenar en el txt mediante fprintf
                    puts("DNI:");
                    scanf("%s", &clientes[i].dni);
                    fprintf(archivo, "%s", clientes[i].dni);

                    puts("Nombre:");
                    scanf("%s", &clientes[i].nombre);
                    fprintf(archivo, "%s", &clientes[i].nombre);

                    puts("Apellidos:");
                    scanf("%s", &clientes[i].apellidos);
                    fprintf(archivo, "%s", &clientes[i].apellidos);

                    puts("Direccion Introduce los espacios con _:");
                    scanf("%s", &clientes[i].direccion);
                    fprintf(archivo, "%s", &clientes[i].direccion);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

}
            fclose(archivo);
            system("cls");

}
```

[Adjunto el código completo para más información necesaria.](https://pastebin.com/ySYmnp4J)
El documento de txt lo cargamos introduciendo el nombre de este por consola.

Comment: ¿Y qué tal una pregunta más concreta tipo *"Me he atascado en este punto"* o *"no me funciona esto de aqui"*? Tu pregunta no sería muy diferente a, por ejemplo, *"¿Cómo puedo migrar esta aplicación de Windows a Linux?"* o, ya puestos *"¿Cómo puedo migrar este código de ensamblador a java?"*. Por favor, intenta hacer preguntas concretas y concisas... aunque ya te avanzo que tu código ya tendría serios problemas para funcionar aun sin usar memoria dinámica... quizás deberías corregir eso antes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No me he parado a leer todo tu código pero te doy una pequeña introducción de la memoria dinámica.

La memoria dinámica úsala cuando no sepas que cantidad quieres tener hasta que no lo ejecutes.
Ejemplo:

- Quiero un programa que trabaje con 10 clientes. (Memoria normal).
- Quiero un programa que trabaje con el número de clientes que le voy a pasar yo durante la ejecución. (Memoria dinámica)

La memoria dinámica no tiene nada que ver con escribir en un archivo.

Aquí un pequeño ejemplo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
   int *edad_clientes;
   int num_clientes;

   scanf("%d", &num_clientes);

   // devuelve un puntero a una zona de memoria reservada para que la uses
   edad_clientes = malloc(sizeof(int) * num_clientes); // por qué sizeof()?, malloc necesita saber el número en bytes de la variable

   for (int i = 0; i < num_clientes; i++)
     scanf("%d", &edad_clientes[i]);

   free(edad_clientes);   // es obligatorio liberar la memoria una vez terminada de usar
   edad_clientes = NULL;   // es de buena praxis poner el anterior puntero a nulo.
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Tu respuesta no responde a las dudas planteadas por el usuario... de hecho para encontrar un tutorial sobre memoria dinámica bastaría con buscar en Internet. Este no es un portal basado en tutoriales sino uno de preguntas y respuestas. Por favor, [edita](/edit) tu pregunta para modificarla siguiendo las reglas establecidas en este sitio: [answer]. También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour]. No tomes esto como una crítica negativa sino como consejos de bienvenida.